# Get no of days in current month in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any efficient way of getting the number of days in current month using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function _getDates(year, month) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); // 0 + number of days
}
console.log(_getDates(2016, 07))
```

Comment: I used 
    https://jsfiddle.net/mf543zh6/
It is not running though